# How to calculate storage footprint (in bytes) for a specific user (and related objects) in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql, saas

My goal is to determine the storage costs incurred per user in a SaaS application.
Lets say the database consists of the following tables:

- user
- userProfile
- userPosts
- userComments

Assuming I have a few months of data, how would I go about determining how much raw storage in bytes each user uses?

It would be helpful to be able to determine the size of each query. That way one can figure out how much data was generated on a monthly basis.

Comment: Does [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row) help?

Comment: "*determine the size of each query*" - which query are you referring to? To determine the size of a **table** you can use `pg_relation_size()` or `pg_total_relation_size()` to included indexes and compressed data.

Comment: just get the relation sizes (using the functions mentioned above) and divide by the numnber of users. Doing so you will have an avg of the sotrage size per user.